# Can we break up the joint CDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

For the continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, is it mathematically correct to say that?

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_{X|Y}(x|y) \cdot F_Y(y)$$

EDIT:

In other words, is it true that...
$$\mathbb P(X \le x, Y \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le x | Y \le y) \cdot \mathbb P(Y \le y) $$

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x | Y\leq y)$ is defined to be $\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)/\mathrm{Pr}(Y\leq
y)$
so, yes,
$\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=
\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x | Y\leq y) \mathrm{Pr}(Y\leq y).$

But I would expect $F_{X|Y}(x|y)$ to mean $\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x|Y=y)$ rather than $\mathrm{Pr}(X\leq x | Y\leq y)$.

Answer (score 2):

With the usual interpretation of $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x|Y=y)$ the equation looks like that: $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y F_{X|Y}(x|z) dP_Y(z)$$